# SQL: Reorder by 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a problem to reorder this. I want to order this by `Username` and `UserType` without broken the `NumRow` order. It should be 1,2,3 etc. Below is the image my current result:

[image]

This is the current sql:

```
WITH ReceiverList AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY receiver.username asc) NumRow,
    receiver.username AS Username,
    user_lookup.user_login_id AS UserID,
    CASE
        WHEN user_lookup.username = user_lookup.user_login_id THEN 'RECEIVER' 
        ELSE 'SUB-RECEIVER' 
    END AS UserType
  FROM receiver
  JOIN user_lookup
    ON receiver.username = user_lookup.username
)

SELECT TOP 4 *
FROM ReceiverList
```

Here is the result I want but the order(`NumRow`) should be 1,2,3,4. This sql I'm using inside datatables ajax to order and search. Please help me guys.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your result, you also want to order by `UserId`:

```
WITH ReceiverList AS (
      SELECT r.username AS Username,
             ul.user_login_id AS UserID,
             (CASE WHEN ul.username = ul.user_login_id THEN 'RECEIVER' 
                   ELSE 'SUB-RECEIVER' 
              END) AS UserType
      FROM receiver r JOIN
           user_lookup ul
           ON r.username = ul.username
     )
SELECT TOP 4
       row_number() over (username, usertype, userid) as rownum
       rl.*
FROM ReceiverList
ORDER BY rownum;
```

You cannot use the `usertype` in the same `SELECT` where it is defined.